# Get value of one level up from \@enumdepth within Enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I'm attempting to write a function which returns the value of the item one level up and the value of the current item within a multilevel enumerate.  Thus far, here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\makeatletter       
\newcommand{\itemAns}{
    \theenumi-\@nameuse{the\@enumctr}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item ~\\
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Actual Output: \itemAns\\ Desired Output: 1-a
        \item ~\\
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Actual Output: \itemAns\\ Desired Output: b-i
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And produces the following output:

[image]

Obviously I would want to use something other than `\theenumi` but I'm not sure how to do something similar to what I did with `\@nameuse{the\@enumctr}` at the appropriate `enumdepth`.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you always want the result to be the value of the previous item at the net higher level, or would a value obtained by a pointer work?  If the latter, you could use the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism to get the exact values.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I need the former.  Though that is a very helpful suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the name using `\@enumdepth`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\itemAns}{%
  \@nameuse{theenum\romannumeral\numexpr\@enumdepth-1\relax}%
  -\@nameuse{the\@enumctr}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \mbox{}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Actual Output: \itemAns\\ Desired Output: 1-a
        \item \mbox{}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Actual Output: \itemAns\\ Desired Output: b-i
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought the solution would be pretty straightforward, and your solution is, so thank you very much, I really appreciate the help